# How does one best integrate with clojure abstractions?

Tags: clojure, abstraction, leaky-abstraction

I am implementing an ordered set in clojure, where I retrieve elements based on their rank. This means that I can retrieve the 4th element (according to the set's ordering), the 3rd, or the 7th, all in logarithmic time.

In order to get my new data structure integrated with clojure's common methods (or "abstractions") such as `conj`, `get`, `nth`, etc., Which is the better way to do it:

1. Actually implement `conj`, for example, in my datatype's protocol, or
2. Implement Rich Hickey's `clojure.lang.IPersistentSet` or some interface like it.

The first seems easier, but also easier to mess up the semantics of the function. The second seems like I am implementing an interface that was never meant to be part of the public API, and the actual methods that are associated with that interface (protocol) are confusingly different. For example, it seems that in order to implement `conj` with my set, I must implement a `cons` method of `clojure.lang.IPersistentSet`, which has a different name. There seems to have little documentation on how this all works, which poses a large challenge in implementing this ranked set.

Which one should I choose? Should I implement my own or the methods of a `clojure.lang` interface? If I should do the latter, where is some good documentation that can guide me through the prosses?

*EDIT*: I want to make it clear that I am trying to make a set from which you can retrieve any element (or "remove" it) in logarithmic time by specifying the element's *rank* (e.g., "give me the 5th element, mr. set."). To my knowledge, no such set yet exists in clojure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I have just released a library called [avl.clj](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/avl.clj) which implements persistent sorted maps and sets with support for the standard Clojure API (they are drop-in replacements for the built-in sorted collections), as well as transients and logarithmic time rank queries (via `clojure.core/nth`)<sup>1</sup>. Both Clojure and ClojureScript are supported; performance on the Clojure side is mostly on a par with the built-in variants in my preliminary benchmarking. Follow the link above if you'd like to give it a try. Any experience reports would be greatly appreciated!

As for the actual question: I'm afraid there isn't much in the way of documentation on Clojure's internal interfaces, but still, implementing them is the only way of making one's custom data structures fit in with the built-ins. [core.rrb-vector](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) (which I have written and now maintain) takes this approach, as do other Contrib libraries implementing various data structures. This is also what I've done with avl.clj, as well as [sorted.clj](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/sorted.clj) (which is basically the ClojureScript port of the red-black-tree-based sorted collections backported to Clojure). All of these libraries, as well as Clojure's own `gvec.clj` file which implements the primitive-storing vectors produced by `clojure.core/vector-of`, can serve as examples of what's involved. (Though I have to say it's easy to miss a method here and there...)

The situation is much simpler in ClojureScript, where all the core protocols are defined at the top of `core.cljs`, so you can just look at the list and pick the ones relevant to your data structure. Hopefully the same will be true on the Clojure side one day.

---

<sup>1</sup> Removal by rank is `(disj my-set (nth my-set 123))` for now. I might provide a direct implementation later on if it turns out to make enough of a difference performance-wise. (I'll definitely write one to check if it does.)

Comment: As of release 0.0.3, avl.clj's maps are unambiguously faster for lookups than the built-in sorted maps and offer noticeably faster construction of large instances thanks to transients. Single (non-transient) `assoc` / `dissoc` are slower -- that's the cost of fast lookups.

Comment: As an aside, why did you choose to use an AVL tree over a red-black tree?

Comment: @djhaskin987 Because of their algorithmic properties -- AVL trees offer significantly faster lookups at the cost of slower insertions / deletions. Transient support is then a way of making these slower "update" operations acceptable in typical scenarios involving multiple updates to neighbouring parts of the tree. (This is a space-time trade-off, of course.)

Comment: For posterity: use this function on a clojure system interface to find out what methods it provides: https://gist.github.com/djhaskin987/75b2fee0e309f3020eb1

Comment: avl.clj has since become a Contrib library – [data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) – and acquired some new features (logarithmic time splits / subcollections).